# Is it possible to call a C Function by reference from python??

Tags: python, c, automated-tests, ctypes

I am a beginner in python and I need to test a C function which is being called by reference.

Here is my C File : myfile.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int my_function(int *x)
{
int A;
printf("enter value of A");
scanf("%d",&A);
*x = 10 * A; // this sets the value to the address x is referencing to
 return 0; 
}
```

now,
my python script should call my_function() and pass the argument so that I can check and verify the result.

something like :

`result = self.loaded_class.my_function(addressOf(some_variable))`

`self.assertEqual(some_variable,10)`

Is this possible ?? how can i achieve this.
And I am writing scripts in python for auto tests , not using interactive python.

Comment: How do you compile you c code? Maybe you can use ctypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile your file as a shared library or dll (I don't know how to do that), you can use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) like this (assuming it's a dll for this example):

```
import ctypes as ct

mylib = ct.cdll.myfile
c_int = ct.c_int(0)
mylib.my_function(ct.byref(c_int))
print c_int.value
```

Comment: I am compiling the file using -shared and then in the script i m using `my_test_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/dir/libfoo.so')` . Is this okay??

Comment: when i am running my script it shows this error            ` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script1.py", line 18, in <module>
    testlib = ctypes.CDLL('~/auto-test/libsample1.so')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ~/auto-test/libsample1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory `

Comment: @Piyush: Your shell expands `'~'` to a valid path. Use `CDLL(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'auto-test', 'libsample1.so'))`.

Comment: @Lauritz V : Thank you very much for the code snippet , it fits seamlessly into my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a Python interface for C function, a simple example is in [Python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example). However, if all you want to do is test C function, you're probably better of with a C/C++ testing framework such as [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/).